# Marathon doesn't deploy an app via PUT /v2/apps/{appId}

Tags: deployment, mesosphere, marathon

Unfortunately I face problems with deployment to Marathon.

I do `curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i http://marathon_url/v2/apps/lookout -d@lookout.json`

And receive response:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)
```

That's it. No `deploymentId` returned in response.
Sometimes it needs to do around 10 `curl` to get an app deployed.

Sometimes I receive `deploymentId`, but anyway nothing changed in Marathon UI.

**Marathon version: 0.9.2**

Does anybody have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

`PUT` is for changing the config of an already deployed app. Use [POST](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html#post-v2-apps) to deploy an app.